# Error while deploying custom Spring XD processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I have a custom processor, which I have modeled after the sample tweet transformer. Upon deployment of a stream with this processor, I get the following error:

```
2015-12-18T08:27:17+0100 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Exception deploying module
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required module artifacts are either missing or invalid. Unable to determine module type for module definition
: 'processor:my-own-processor'.
```

I have a ModuleConfiguration.java, which looks like this (minus the imports)

```
package com.my.package.myprocessor;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ModuleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    MessageChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    MessageChannel output() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    MyProcessor transformer() {
        return new MyProcessor();
    }
}
```

The processor itself looks like this:

```
package com.my.package.myprocessor;

@MessageEndpoint
public class MyProcessor {

   MyProcessor() {
      // do some initialization      
   }

   @Transformer( inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output" )
   public String transform( String payload ) 
   {
      return "Hello World!";
   }
}
```

I have also added a spring-module.properties under src/main/resources and a spring-module.xml. Both get copied to resources/ in the resulting jar file -- I checked this after mvn package.

The spring-module.properties is simple:

```
base_packages=com.my.package.myprocessor
```

and the spring-module.xml states the same as the module configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">
    <channel id="input"/>

    <transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
        <beans:bean class="com.my.package.myprocessor.MyProcessor"/>
    </transformer>

    <channel id="output"/>
</beans:beans>
```

I uploaded the module like this:

```
module upload --file ~/Programs/my-processor/target/my-processor-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-runtime-dependencies.jar --name my-processor --type processor
```

And created the stream like this:

```
stream create --name my-processor --definition "input: file --mode=lines | aixigo-vgm | output: file" --deploy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing I noticed: I am building a nested jar with the assembly plugin to provide all my runtime dependencies. When I leave this step out, I can deploy just fine. So my question seems to rather be: How can I deploy such a nested jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed the packaging. I opted now to the spring boot plugin to package an uber jar like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
           <layout>MODULE</layout>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The most important thing here is the MODULE layout. This is mentioned in the XD docs, but poorly documented elsewhere.